# Iterate and connect to proxies?

Tags: 14.04, proxy

New guy here,

Is there a way to iterate through a list of proxies and connect to each within a *.txt* file using the Ubuntu terminal? If so, how?

My Ubuntu distro is 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

If im right you have a list of proxies and you want to connect to them in terminal.

Im using [Cow Project](https://github.com/cyfdecyf/cow) you can set list of proxies in all kind (HTTP,Socks5 ,Shadowsocks and ...) and connect to them in 3 strategies:

1- backup:  default policy, use the first prarent proxy in config,the others are just backup

2-hash:    hash to a specific parent proxy according to host name

3-latency: use the parent proxy with lowest connection latency

Install and configure Cow then you have one http proxy at front with so many at backend